# "Method does not override method from its superclass" - When creating ContextMenu in Android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to show contextmenu on longpress in **MainActivity.java**. But I'm getting error *"Method does not override method from its superclass"* on **@Override** and *"Cannot resolve symbol ... "* for both **ContextMenu** and **ContextMenuInfo** in the **onCreateContextMenu** method.

My code is:

```
package com.syver.adhper;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.*;
import android.view.View;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        createpnl();
        //more codes here
   }
   @Override
   public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
   {
       //some codes here
       //error is only in this section at @Override, ContextMenu and ContextMenuInfo
   }
   public void createpnl()
   {
       registerForContextMenu(...); //... means a layout
       //more codes here
   }
}
```

Why am I getting this error? What should I do to avoid this error? Please give me corrected complete code as I'm new in android developing. I have searched here and also google, but proper ans I did't find and also didn't understand.[image]

My API is 19 (kitkat)

Comment: I see that there's also an error for `ContextMenu` & `ContextMenuInfo`. I think you're missing a couple of imports, the `@Override` error is likely solved if you imported those classes

Comment: what should I import? :)

Comment: You should get some suggestions if you hover over those classes

Comment: I'm new in android. Can you tell me with example?

Comment: `import android.view.ContextMenu;` `import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;`

Comment: thanks, it worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, it work in my android studio

```
 @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu (ContextMenu menu,
                              View v,
                              ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
    {

    }
```

reference:https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html
also import the class by click the red, and press alt+enter, choose import the class, I think this would solve your problem